# Show default image if no image exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos

I run Apache on Centos 5 and I want to implement rewrite rule. When user is trying to access the image in folder `/var/site.com/html/image/products/` the rule should check if image exists, if not,  I want `/var/site.com/html/image/defaultimage.jpg` to be shown

I tried to put this in .htaccess which located in  `/var/site.com/html/image/products/` but it did not work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule .* /var/site.com/html/image/defaultimage.jpg [L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target (2nd param) of a `RewriteRule` can be a file-path or a URI-path, and apache tries to guess which one you mean. For some reason, if it starts with a `/`, it's inclined to think it's a URI-path. Try removing the document root from the target:

```
RewriteRule .* /image/defaultimage.jpg [L]
```