# How to show a default image if original image is not exist

Tags: image, .htaccess

I have my `.htaccess` file `localhost/site/` folder and a default image `defaultcarimage-thumb.jpg` in `localhost/site/images/car_model/` folder.I want to show this default image instead of main image when original image will not be found. For that I search on google and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643640/show-default-image-if-no-image-exists)

And I edit my `.htaccess` as follows :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule .*/images/car_model/defaultcarimage-thumb.jpg [L]
```

But nothing change. What's wrong with this code? Or Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RewriteRule syntax is `RewriteRule _url-send-by-user_ _rewrite-to_`

So change your RewriteRule to something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /images/car_model/defaultcarimage-thumb.jpg [L]
```

And check the Pathes, both the RewriteBase and RewriteRule-to argument path.

Comment: Actually I think you are right.But I missed something to mention here that the oiriginal images are icon.They are defined in CSS like `#idname { background: url(../images/icon.png) no-repeat; }` .How can I replace the missing icon with the default image?

Comment: Its irrelevant if you use the image in an <img>-tag or in an css-block. If your default image would not be shown, try to put the .htaccess in your `/images`-folder, change `RewriteRule (.*) defaultcarimage-thumb.jpg[L]`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried in such way but it still not working.I am working with jquery mobile and I don't know it is a jquery mobile problem or not. I have to show the default icon in list-view

Comment: If like me if anyone already had a redirect for images to something else then *don't* add the `[L]` at the end for that redirect rule and put these rules after that. So if all else fails this rule is executed.